# Why Windows gcc (cygwin) do not write ELF header?

Tags: c++, debugging, gcc, compilation, dwarf

In a linux machine, when we compile, for example the piece of code below:

b.cc:

```
typedef struct sTeste {
    int campo1;
    char campo2;
    int campo3;


} T_TESTE;


void m1(T_TESTE *p) {

}
```

with the command:

> gcc  -gdwarf-2 -c b.cc -o b.o

we get the ELF header

```
root@marceloaleks:~# hd b.o |head
00000000  7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.ELF............|
00000010  01 00 3e 00 01 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |..>.............|
00000020  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  a8 03 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000030  00 00 00 00 40 00 00 00  00 00 40 00 14 00 11 00  |....@.....@.....|
00000040  55 48 89 e5 48 89 7d f8  5d c3 00 00 b1 00 00 00  |UH..H.}.].......|
00000050  02 00 00 00 00 00 08 01  00 00 00 00 04 00 00 00  |................|
00000060  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000070  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 02 00 00 00 00 0c 01  |................|
00000080  01 64 00 00 00 03 00 00  00 00 01 02 64 00 00 00  |.d..........d...|
00000090  02 23 00 03 00 00 00 00  01 03 6b 00 00 00 02 23  |.#........k....#|
```

00000000  7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.**ELF**............|

However, when we do the same on Windows the result is :

```
C:\Aleks-IOT\Code\Dev\JAVA\nbdwarfdumplib>xxd b.o |head
00000000: 6486 0d00 0000 0000 ae05 0000 1c00 0000  d...............
00000010: 0000 0400 2e74 6578 7400 0000 0000 0000  .....text.......
00000020: 0000 0000 1000 0000 1c02 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000030: 0000 0000 0000 0000 2000 5060 2e64 6174  ........ .P`.dat
00000040: 6100 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  a...............
```

My real problem is that I would like to extract the dwarf debug data from only a simple compilation unit (b.cc in this case).

Any Clue ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have Windows 10 64-bit? You can try [Ubuntu on Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/install_guide), which will let you build and run ELF binaries in a Windows cmd or powershell window. It is preview quality - I've gotten BSODs just using `apt-get` - but it works.

Comment: I will take a try

Answer (score 4):

Because Windows doesn't use ELF.  Windows uses PE (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable).  If you want ELF in Windows, just get GCC source and build it yourself with an elf target during the ./configure stage.

However, you wouldn't be able to run the output in Windows.

In PE, the debug info is stored as symbols in the COFF symbol table.  You can get to it via Windows API:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx

There's a bunch of free tools using it to let you peek into PE files.  For example: https://sourceforge.net/projects/nktspeview/

Comment: Yes, but i wasn´t able to get the dwarf data in windows without have a executable generated. Thank you. 
dwarfdump works perfectly in Linux !
Do you know how to get a PE  for just a source ?

Comment: I added some details.  You may want to do a web search for PE file viewers.  I don't know which is best.  It's been a long time since I worked in this area.

Comment: I don´t want to use the PE format, because it resides only in the windows world and my application needs to run in Linux and MAcOS too. But you talked about generate gcc to get elf; that´s a good idea and i will try.

Comment: I think you would need to rebuild your app to run for Linux and Mac.  Even though they are both ELF, the syscalls aren't compatible.  Why not just build on a Linux machine?  Otherwise, you have to set up cross compilation toolchain in Windows, which is OK, but then you wouldn't be able to test your app by running it (on Windows).

Comment: I do not want to run my application, I only need to compile on any OS, so  i get the dwarf symbols generated. 
I am creating a RPC framework using the symbols so I can get the entire description of the methods and its parameters. In this way I do not need to create the interface with the aid of some IDL. –

Comment: well you don't need to look at the executable for this.  you can just generate the symbol file separately and look at the symbol file.

Comment: Yes,  this is the point. In linux it works, but not in windows.  I create a workarount linking the source with a dummy main, so i am able to read the compileUnits and all debug  sections.

Comment: gcc has an option to output dwarf data in a separate file.  maybe you want to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know what version you are using. In Linux gcc can be:
- GCC standard (compile C)
- GCC-elf  (compile C with Elf)

In Windows too but it is more difficult to have Elf